# Отображение темы в приложении

Tags: javafx

Разрабатываю дизайн для приложения Java FX. 
Во вкладке Preview > Themes нашёл список разнообразных тем.
При выборе одной из их(Gluon Mobile Light) дизайн изменился и на пред просмотре(Preview > Show Preview in Windows) можно увидеть изменения.
Но при запуске приложения отображает стандартная тема. Как отобразить данную тему В приложении Java FX?

Comment: В JDK видел только упоминания про Modena и Caspian. Думаю можно выцепить Gluon из сценБилдера и установить в приложение. 
С темами не работал, но судя по местоположению смотреть в сторону         Application.setUserAgentStylesheet();
        PlatformImpl.isCaspian()
        PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet();

Comment: @Maxim Вероятнее всего, это будет нарушением лицензии на Gluon Mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти темы входят в комплект [Gluon Mobile (условия и цены)](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/buy/). Для использования нужен плагин для вашей IDE — поддерживаются NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA and Eclipse (http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.4.1/#_project_setup).

Компоненты с "материальным" дизайном еще есть в другой библиотеке — [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) (Apache License 2.0).